# Shape Keys export to FBX (for 3Ds Max)

Tags: export, error, shape-keys, .fbx, obj

There are many shape keys in a blender file. I'm trying to export all of these as a single FBX. When I export as FBX, the morpher modifier appears in 3ds MAX. All good so far. But none of the morphers are working. For example; When I change the "Joy" value, nothing changes in the 3d model. When I extract the "joy" mesh from the Morpher channel, I get a broken mesh. How can I solve this problem? Is there a script for that? I would be very happy if you could help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem...
To export shape keys from Blender file as FBX:

1- Select the objects you want to export and go to the export menu and choose Collada (.dae). Check "Include Shape Keys" and start export.

2- Start a new Blender

3- Import Collada into blender

4. Export the imported model as FBX again.
5. Import this fbx in 3Ds Max.

You will see the Morpher modifier running.

I hope it will be a useful solution for those who have this problem. I've been trying to fix this problem for days and by chance I found the solution.

[image]

[image]